# How to align all **vessels** to be in the same direction?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, alignment, medical

I am working on a medical image processing project in which I want to detect the equation of the **vessels** in the image. I want to normalize the dataset so that all the **major vessels** are pointing in the same direction. For example, the image is: [image: Input imagw1]

The major vessels will be marked as: [image: marked image 1]

For input image,

[image: Input image 2]

The major vessels will be marked as: [image: marked image 2]

I want to automatically detect the direction and perform rotation on the 2nd input image to be like:

[image: Rotated image 2]

How do I detect these vessels and perform alignment accordingly?

**Edit**:

Till now, I tried to use the code below:

```
clear global
clc
warning on
addpath(genpath('\D:\OCT_enface_registration\codes\ode_alignment\'));

img = imread('D:\OCT_enface_registration\data\RPEDC\OD_circle\Khader Pasha Sk _2246_AngioVue Disc_OS_2016-06-15_02.png');

%Perform histogram
imgHist = histeq(img);

%Set up the threshold value
Threshold = 120;

%The vessels are extracted using Kirsch templates. It is an operator (mapping) to find the maximum
%edge strength in a few predetermined directions.
bloodVessels = VesselExtract(imgHist(:,:,1), Threshold);
im = im2double(imgHist);

% Convert RGB to Gray via PCA
lab = rgb2lab(im);
f = 0;
wlab = reshape(bsxfun(@times,cat(3,1-f,f/2,f/2),lab),[],3);
[C,S] = pca(wlab);
S = reshape(S,size(lab));
S = S(:,:,1);
gray = (S-min(S(:)))./(max(S(:))-min(S(:)));

%% Background Exclusion
% Apply Average Filter of [9 9] size
h = fspecial('average', [9 9]);

%Gray image having the dimensions of  [9 9]
JF = imfilter(gray, h);
%figure, imshow(JF);

% Take the difference between the gray image and Average Filter
Z = imsubtract(JF, gray);
%figure, imshow(Z);

%% Threshold using the IsoData Method (Iterative Self-Organizing Data Analysis Technique)
%It is a method of unsupervised classification to cluster a data depedning
%on threshold values.
%More information: http://web.pdx.edu/~jduh/courses/Archive/geog481w07/Students/Vassilaros_ISODATA.pdf
level=isodata(Z); % this is our threshold level

%% Convert to Binary
BW = imbinarize(Z, level-.008);

%% Remove small pixels
BW2 = bwareaopen(BW, 100);

%% Overlay: Image put on another image
BW2 = imcomplement(BW2);
out = imoverlay(imgHist, BW2, [0 0 0]);
%figure, imshow(out);
samp=imgaussfilt(double(BW2));
samp1=samp>0.9;
figure;imshow(samp1);
samp2=samp<0.1;
%figure;imshow(samp2);
%figure;imshow(samp2, 'ColorMap', [1 1 1; 1 0 0]);
```

I am getting images like this:

[image: Output image]

It is showing me all the vessels after segmentation but I want to only find the major vessel.

Comment: Let me ask the classic question: what have you tried? I assume you do not want us to do it for you.

Comment: Along with Ander's question, please specify how you define the "major vessel"

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I have made the required edits and added the code that I have tried.

Comment: @Raha, it is the vessels that have the brightest intensity. Sometimes, there is more than one equally bright vessel.